# How to communicate two templates in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I'm uploading csv file in a page and then I want to show the preview of the same in a popup.
In preview page either I used to click save button or cancel button.Then I want to clear the file form browse button . How its possible in angular js?

Comment: You need to type your question more clearly and provide sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between components through services:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    var obj = {
        name: "csv"
    };

    return {
        get: function() {
            return obj;
        }
    };
});
```

And then use them in your controllers:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.get();
}

function MyOtherCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.get();
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3139/